# ClassNotFoundException - axis2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am having following exception while deploying axis2 webservices

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:164)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.Scheduler$SchedulerTimerTask.run(Scheduler.java:93)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:404)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getServiceClass(Utils.java:780)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:412)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getServiceClass(Utils.java:777)
    ... 16 more
[ERROR] The BookOrderingServiceImpl service, which is not valid, caused The following error occurred during schema generation: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:164)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.Scheduler$SchedulerTimerTask.run(Scheduler.java:93)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:404)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getServiceClass(Utils.java:780)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:412)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getServiceClass(Utils.java:777)
    ... 16 more
[INFO] org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl
```

But if you check the com.unilib.service.BookOrderingServiceImpl class is there.

[image]

All three (`BookInformationServiceImpl`, `BookInventoryServiceImpl` and `StudentServiceImpl`) services were deployed successfully. But unable to deploy `BookOrderingServiceImpl`. I have checked that all libs of axis2 are there (in build path). I have no idea why its not been publised.

**BookOrderingServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.unilib.service;

public class BookOrderingServiceImpl implements BookOrderingService {

    @Override
    public String orderBook(Integer studentId, String studentPin, String bookIsbn) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the project and try ?

Comment: Yeah I did. clean the server then run on server and try to publish webservice

Comment: The `BookOrderingServiceImpl` is not found in the class path somehow and hence the ClassNotFoundException.